# User's phone number in messenger bot?

Tags: facebook, messenger

Is it possible to get user's phone number from web hook sent by messenger bot when a user initiates a chat? 
I need to check if a user by phone number is existing in my database or not.

Comment: No it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do it, check it.

*https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile*

One system you can apply, when anyone enter the bot first time check the psid in this user exist in db or not, so when if not exist, send a message "Please enter your number", if number match the db then update psid.

So need to access user phone number once time in chatbot lifetime,because when after verification you again insert the chatbot, it shows you verified because your psid then exist.